# How to change interface language for Firefox 58, e.g. in developer tools?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

Just wondering, how to change interface language in last ff versions (58ff, 58 ff developer edition)?

Advise "go to about:config" and change general.useragent.locale there (after switching off intl.locale.matchOS) - did not help, and I'm still have e.g. russian, but want English.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Install en-US https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/english-us-language-pack/ and have key `intl.locale.requested` set to `en-US` in `about:config`.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-firefox-interface-other-languages-language-pack